# Way to know when a question was auto bumped even after it was changed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, old-questions, bump

When old question without accepted answer is auto bumped to front page, we see it as edited by "Community" user - all good.

However, once there is other activity in the question - new answer or edit, that auto bump indication is lost. It does not appear in any edit history and probably not even in the moderator/10K tools like deleted posts.

Is it possible to preserve some indication of the auto bump, for example as part of the question edit history?

Motivation for this request is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist/5848133#5848133), posted today to old question - so I wonder if the user saw it in front page and thought it's new question or explicitly digged that old question somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *feature-request* is now complete. Notification of community user bump is preserved in post timeline and revision history.

Screenshot of Revision History:

> [image: Revision History]

Screenshot of Post Timeline:

> [image: Timeline]

Comment: Totally forgot about this feature request, lol... Thanks! :)

Comment: You are welcome :) With 146 feature-requests under your belt this probably took the longest to become status-complete

Comment: Yup, longest indeed. Those that were completed (about 30) took less than a year in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

From [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3359414/timeline) one can see that the question was not recently bumped to the front page: the other answer got its first upvote on 
Dec 11 '10, so there was no bumping afterwards. ([Community bumps only non-negatively scored questions with no upvoted answers.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/moderator-clean-up-of-abandoned-poor-quality-questions/2099#2099)) So, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist/5848133#5848133) that was your motivation was *not* posted after Community did some poking.

Nevertheless I support your feature-request. I've thought more than once that it would be useful to have an indication of "commutity bumps" in the edit history: Sometimes I see that someone *edits* a post for very minor reasons, which usually annoys me, but I find it perfectly OK if the question is anyway already on the front page.

Comment: Cool hidden feature, thanks! And thanks for the support as well.. :)