# What's Changed In This Question?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to know when a question was auto bumped even after it was changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89520/way-to-know-when-a-question-was-auto-bumped-even-after-it-was-changed)

This isn't a request for a specific feature. It is a step before that. It is highlighting a use-case that I frequently encounter that isn't handled well by the site, to bring it to the attention of the SE staff who look after the UX.

Sometimes I noticed that some old question has had some activity. I'll frequently check it out (sometimes for interest, mostly to patrol for crap - "regression to the mean" suggests that activity on old questions with highly-quality accepted answers is uncommonly an improvement.)

At this point, I have a tricky task. I want to find what has recently changed: has the question been edited? a new answer? one of the existing answers? has something been deleted?

That can be clumsy and slow - especially for questions with lots of long answers.

It would be nice to have a mechanism to find the most recent changes made.

I can't search for today's date, because it might say "3 hours ago" instead (and time-zones make it tricky)

Complication: As mod, I *think* I see all changes. Regular users might not be able to see that the recent change was the deletion of an answer, making the recent activity even more mysterious.

> **Related Question**: [Detail Recent Favorite changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes)

Comment: Click on question, see if last edit time was recent.  If not, click on `active` just above the answers and see how recently the top one was edited.  If you stay in active first sorting mode, you can go through all your questions this way.  There's also a timeline view which gives you everything in most-recent-activity-first list.  For instance: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/44435/timeline  It requires a bit of URL editing though, but if you use it often enough it's not hard to make a bookmarklet for it.

Comment: In addition to everything Adam said, any post with activity after the initial post has an "active" section in the sidebar, just under the view counter. If you click on the time there, it will go to the most recently active post.

Comment: This is great, I never discovered that. Thanks. (Given several people have asked about it, it suggests a FAQ entry.)