# Is it possible to find out how many times a certain question has been bumped by Community?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, community-user, bump

Just curious... is it possible to find out **how many times** and **when** a specific question has been bumped by [the community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)?
If not, can this data (if it exists) be made available (hence the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag as well - I'll remove it if it *is* possible).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89520/way-to-know-when-a-question-was-auto-bumped-even-after-it-was-changed (yep, shameless self promotion ;-))

Comment: @ShadowWizard very similar! (but completely different :P) +1

Comment: Well, if my request would be applied, it would become trivial to fulfil yours...

Comment: @Sha still different though! But I agree - it would and it should!

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Shog9 it would be interesting to know how many times a question has been bumped - (kind of what my question you just answered stemmed from!) ('just curious').

Comment: huh? Did you ninja-edited the reasoning out, @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ? I can swear seeing a reason like "this can be used to determine what questions would be auto bumped next", no?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I though that deserved to be another question:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257629/should-we-change-communitys-bumps-according-to-the-amount-of-times-a-question-h...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of about a week ago, there's a new PostHistory record added when Community bumps a post:

[image]

Comment: This was not tracked prior to last week. Applying retroactively is not possible.