# Should we change Community's bumps according to the amount of times a question has *already* been bumped

Tags: discussion, community-user, bump

The Community user bumps questions regularly - and sometimes bumps *the same question* multiple times.

Shouldn't there should be less (or more) priority for questions that have *already* been bumped by Community?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there should be.

**And there is**: when a question is bumped, its "Last Activity Date" is updated to the current time, which disqualifies it from being bumped by [Community](/users/-1) again during the next 30 days.

Given there's also an element of randomness in the logic by which eligible questions are chosen, you really shouldn't see questions being bumped very often unless there are simply *very few* questions that qualify.

Comment: ah. I guess that is kind of it. **But** I was thinking more like: If a question has been bumped 2 times in the past, give another question a higher chance of being bumped.

Comment: But on high volume sites with lots of candidates, one question can be bumped 20 times in two years span, while other question not even once - I think OP is trying to address those cases.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes!

Comment: My considered opinion on this matter is: "whooooooooooooooooooooo cares?" @Sha

Comment: I care. Isn't it enough? :-)

Comment: So... A question remains eligible (scores >= 0, not closed or deleted, has answer(s) but none of them are accepted or up- or down-voted) for *two years*... And your big concern is that it *might* get bumped once a month, @Sha?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the auto bump to begin with, @Sho? Of course I don't personally care for each and every question, it's the concept, and in my opinion if going that way (auto bumping to give second chance) better go all the way and make it as fair as possible. Those small/tiny details are what makes Stack Exchange such a unique place.

Comment: The purpose of the auto-bump is to get a bit more attention for questions that *might very well be answered* but for which we have nothing to indicate this. Given the multitude of purposes for a question's "answered" state, this is a very practical consideration. It has little to do with "fairness", nor am I certain what that would even mean in this context; generally, the only time anyone notices this possibility is when there are so few qualifying questions on a site that they *all* get bumped once every 30 days. @Sha