# Is there a limit to the number of times "community" can bump a question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, community-user, bump

## How many bumps is too many?

Is there a limit to the number of times "[Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)" can bump a question? There are questions with one or more unvoted answers that do not attract views, that do not attract the attention of hi-rep users, that do not attract upvotes for *several* years.

Curiously, questions that have not received *any* answer or where an answer was submitted but later deleted, are never bumped by the system.

Questions can be bumped by the system (i.e. “community”) for two reasons:

1. There are no *upvoted* answers
2. The OP did not *accept* an answer.

On the smaller sites this can be quite annoying, the same post can resurface month after month for years on end.

## How to stop the bumping

Solutions include; upvoting an answer that is half-decent, downvoting the OP, voting to close the OP, or posting an answer in the hope of it being upvoted.  But still, after years of being bumped, month after month, when is it time to put a post to rest, once and for all?

If I've understood correctly, some sites impose restrictions on the [*number of questions*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7542448#7542448) Community user can bump on a given day. But I am talking about the number of *years* a question can be bumped. According to one commenter, the [buck stops here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_buck_stops_here), i.e. with the community.

> *No limit, people should vote to sort the problem out, and rare exceptions have been made*.

### Bump bonus:

- What is the most bumped question in the history of the Stack Exchange network?

References:

1. [Should we change Community's bumps according to the amount of times a question has *already* been bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257629/should-we-change-communitys-bumps-according-to-the-amount-of-times-a-question-h)
2. [Way to know when a question was auto bumped even after it was changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89520/way-to-know-when-a-question-was-auto-bumped-even-after-it-was-changed)
3. [Is it possible to find out how many times a certain question has been bumped by Community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257627/is-it-possible-to-find-out-how-many-times-a-certain-question-has-been-bumped-by)
4. [Question re-bumped by community every month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293393/question-re-bumped-by-community-every-month)
5. On Stack Overflow Meta
   [Why is the Community User so determined to bump this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346604/)

Comment: @Rob This question is different from the second question (mine) because that one asks about *general* limits on Community bumps (i.e. when will and won't questions *in general* be bumped), while this asks about bump limits for *specific questions*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no limit; I've never seen staff mention it in formulas, and I'm pretty sure it would make the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/295232) if it existed.

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273462/most-often-bumped-questions-networkwide), there are currently 2 questions which were bumped a whopping 39 times in their history:

- [Violating a cancelable oath?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43373) on Mi Yodeya
- [Прописная/строчная буква при перечислении названий граф](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/4852) on Russian Stack Exchange

However, this is not the complete answer, because the feature existed for longer, and the events are only recorded from 2016 (both in SEDE and in the question's timeline).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!  Two more things, your answer suggests that the questions in the sede query are dated from 2016 matching when the timeline feature was added, does that mean any "unanswered" question posted earlier does not appear in the results?

Comment: Last thing, looking at the unanswered but still opened questions on EL&U, I saw many examples similar to this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251094/replacing-and-with-comma where it appears to have **never been bumped**. How come?

Comment: Community doesn't bump questions without an answer (it would make sense if it did, but we have another mechanism to bring those under attention, the [Unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) tab). I assume bumping worked more or less the same before 2016, with the only difference that those events weren't registered. The questions I mentioned are from 2014 resp. 2012.

Comment: Would downvoting an answer remove the question from the bump list?

Comment: Yes, unless there are other answers still scoring 0. Shog9 posted the criteria for bumping [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/295232).

Comment: Any idea as to why this question attracted 5 downvotes? Does it sound like a feature request? The title is pretty clear to me. Any suggestions as to why are welcomed, thanks. P.S it's for future reference because it's not worth editing the post any further.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no idea (I upvoted it).