# Expose information about Community bumps, preferably in the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, community-user, bump

I would like to have some way of knowing when Community has bumped a post. Currently, unless you "catch Community in the act" (i.e. examine the question before anybody else makes a change to it or one of its answers), it is impossible to know at what times a question has been Community-bumped. (Yes, in some cases, you can deduce that Community would never have had a chance to bump a post, but that's besides the point.)

The reason I want to know is this: I want to be able to quantify the extent to which a particular class of crappy question (identification requests on Anime.SE) are occupying space on the front page. Since these questions go unanswered at a considerably higher rate than other questions, it's not just a simple matter of counting the rate at which the crappy questions are posted versus other questions; we also need to account for the frequency with which they get kicked back to the front page by Community in order to get a full picture of how much they're occupying space that would otherwise be occupied by other questions.

It would be best if this information were exposed in the Data Explorer (since my goal is to analyze this stuff in aggregate rather than to observe bumps on individual posts I happen to encounter). I don't know how feasible this is, but it seems like one approach would be to add an entry to the PostHistory table (with a new type "Post Bumped by Community") whenever Community bumps a question.

Comment: Well, having it appear in the revisions list [as I've suggested before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89520/way-to-know-when-a-question-was-auto-bumped-even-after-it-was-changed) will also have same effect as far I as I can tell. :)

Comment: is closing / voting down these questions an option? (you mentiond that they are troublesome)

Comment: @gnat The question of what to do with these questions is well-trodden, and the current consensus is that certain varieties (only those lacking detail or too easily googleable) are subject to closure; despite this, the questions continue to come in at an alarming rate. If you care, I have [a post on our meta where I try (and seemingly fail) to persuade people that we should just get rid of all of them](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1193/), and honestly, the point of this feature request is pretty much to get another data point for that post.

Comment: understood, thank you. From that meta post you referred, your reasons to want this data look quite compelling

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257627/260841

Comment: [There is now a PostHistory entry for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/is-there-any-way-to-see-which-posts-community-has-bumped/279201#279201), but it's not yet in Data Explorer.

Answer (score 8):

At some point between Shog's [10 May 2016 answer elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279201/) and today (13 Sept 2016), `PostHistory` entries with `PostHistoryTypeId = 50` ("CommunityBump") were added to the Data Explorer. Hooray!